# Why is the "nonuniqueness" of algebraic closures such an issue?

Tags: field-theory

in algebra one usually proves, that every field $k$ has an algebraic closure $\bar k$ and that all algebraic closures of $k$ are isomorphic. Now I started wondering why people make such a big thing of choosing **an** algebraic closure, instead of choosing **the** algebraic closure. I do know that in general for two algebraic closures $\bar k$ and $\bar k'$ of $k$ there are many isomorphisms and that the algebraic closure therefore doesn't have an universal property, but why is this such a big thing?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have the theorem that for any two algebraic closures $\overline{k_1}$ and $\overline{k_2}$ of $k$ there exists an isomorphism $\overline{k_1}\cong \overline{k_2}$ over $k$.

Here it is important that the isomorphism in the theorem is nearly always highly non-unique (it can be composed with any k-automorphism of $\overline{k_2}$, of which there are many in general). Thus, one should *never write* $\overline{k_1}= \overline{k_2}$; one should always keep track of the choice of isomorphism.

In particular, one should always speak of *an* algebraic closure rather than *the* algebraic closure; there is no “preferred” algebraic closure except in cases when there are no non-trivial automorphisms over $k$.

So this is not a "big thing", but worth to mention it, I guess.

Comment: Ok, i was convinced by the argument that you after the choice of two closures are not able to write $\bar k_1= \bar k_2$

Comment: So why do we talk about "the" splitting field of a polynomial?

Comment: @ElliotG The reason is perhaps that much more people are aware that a splitting field is not unique than that an algebraic closure is not unique. In addition, in most examples of splitting fields we have some easy explicit expressions in mind, from which we could choose  a "preferred" splitting field; for example, for $f(x)=x^3-7$ we have many nice explicit candidates, such as  $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$, or $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_6)$ with a third root of unity $\omega$,  and a sixth root of unity $\zeta_6$ etc. For an algebraic closure this seems more difficult in general.